# Change object values inside a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question might have been asked a few times, but the error I get is quite strange. I just started off with Javascript a week ago.

I have a function which changes the declared objects's attributes. For a simplistic recreation of the problem I have added the snippet below.

I'm trying to add an object to an array a few times and in another for loop, I'm trying to change the values of the attributes of the object on the inside of the array.

```js
function dataPacket(buffer, label) {
  var packet = {
    data: []
  }

  var packetArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    packetArray.push(packet);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    packetArray[i].data = buffer[i];
    console.log("At " + i + "= " + packetArray[i].data);
  }

  console.log(packetArray[0].data);
  console.log(packetArray[1].data);
}

dataPacket([
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
], ["random data in strings"]);
```

When the 1st for loop is printing out the value of the array the values seem to be different on both the indices, but as when the console logging outside the loop has been called, both the value on both the indices seem to be the same. It looks like it has been overwritten after the second loop.

I might be doing something silly.
I also tried this and the results seem to be okay, but this process has to be done in a for loop to keep the process dynamic.

```
console.log("Size of array: " + packetArray.length);
packetArray[0].data = buffer[0];
console.log("Buffer at 0: " +  packetArray[0].data);
packetArray[1].data = buffer[1];
console.log("Buffer at 1: " + packetArray[1].data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because same `packet` object is pushed in array and when you change `packet` data from anywhere it gets reflected where ever it is referenced. Try below, I just removed object `packet`

```js
function dataPacket( buffer, label ) {
    
    var packetArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
      packetArray.push({ data:[] });
    }

    for(var i = 0; i< buffer.length; i++) {
      packetArray[i].data = buffer[i];
      console.log("At " + i + "= " + packetArray[i].data);
    }

    console.log(packetArray[0].data);
    console.log(packetArray[1].data);

}

dataPacket([ [1,2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8,9] ], ["random data in strings"] );
```

Comment: This worked. I have to say this language is a little different from C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

You create one `packet` and push that to multiple positions of the array. That won't copy the packet, but references it. Changing `packetArray[0]` does change `packet` and therefore `packetArray[1]` as they are all referencing the same thing. Move the `packet` declaration into the loop to create a new packet for each index.

I'd write it as:

```
 const packetArray = Array.from(buffer, data => ({ data }));
```